# Coverting String to char Array throwing an error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java

I am Beginner in java ,I am just trying out to convert string into char array,though it is running fine on my System but on a competitive coding website it is throwing an error.Here is the link of that [Question](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/implementation/basics-of-implementation/practice-problems/algorithm/palindromic-ciphers/) **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException**

[image]

Here is my piece of code I have used BufferedReader to take input:-

```
                String s1;
                s1= inp.readLine();
                String s2;
                s2=s1;
                char ch1[] = s1.toCharArray();
                char ch2[] = s2.toCharArray();
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize `String s1` so its value is `null` and you get a `NullPointerException`. Initialize s1 with `String s1 = "";` This should already work. Otherwise just use for test case and for the beginning a random value to initialize.

EDIT:

Comment: No. `s1` is initialised here: `s1= inp.readLine();`.

Comment: Yes  s1=" "; is not working  here

Comment: Then both are initialized and there should not be a problem. That's the only thing I can think of. Maybe `inp.readLine()` gives null.

Comment: Maybe print `inp.readLine()` , if it's null, that may causes the problem

Comment: Yes `inp` is null I guess. Otherwise the code would work.

Comment: Actually Code is working and giving the correct output,but still it is giving a run time error..

Comment: Then the error is in some code you are not showing us. If you run it through a debugger, you will see exactly which line is causing the problem.